# Distributed data storage for slow network with high node churn?

Tags: cloud-storage, distributed-computing

What distributed data storage shall I use for reliably storing data over set of nodes with poor networking between them?

I want something that:

- Does not expect that all nodes are reachable now, including support of offline operation;
- Initially store data locally, but eventually (when networking is good and more nodes online) spread it to necessary other nodes;
- Have good automatic rebalancing and repairing in face of nodes join and leave the network;
- Handle nodes that greatly differs in capacity, storing only small and high priority things on little nodes;
- Treat the local node special: "my" data is always stored on local node first, then backed up to other nodes.

Most solutions like Tahoe-LAFS or GlusterFS seem to expect more or less stable set of nodes kept online and connected with good network, with no extended planned downtimes. Is there a special distributed storage that expectes nodes to be offline on regular basis?

Comment: I don't think you're going to find any that "expect" downtime. The best you'll get are those that are able to work around downtime via proper journaling and parity - and even those will have limits (and require more storage to extend the expectation of downtime to more nodes). What is the reason that you need "expected" downtime built in to your solution? Wouldn't fixing the reason to expect downtime be the first step to implementing a solution?

Comment: For example, because of various nodes can be regular PCs, smartphones and servers. Between server nodes it should work more or less like traditional grid storages. But on a smartphone it should work [quantitively] differently. Nodes that are offline should also do something useful, like sustaining access to small-but-high-prio data (that is copied across all nodes in the network). The storage should not be centered around performance, but around reliability "built with poor bricks and poor cement".

Comment: Note: "offline" here means "operating, but without network". In offline mode node should provide access to the resource it have locally and accept new data, uploading that data to the network when the node finally does online.